# How to get entry from mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I searched the answers that are similar to mine but the answers didn't work, here's my code I don't know what's wrong in it, it keeps getting blank array [] :

```
mongo_client.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ascii)', function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var collection = db.collection('newcol');
    var cursor = collection.find();
    cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.send(docs); 
    });
});
```

Can someone explain why I keep getting an empty array?

Comment: Code looks right; are you sure you have docs in the `newcol` collection of the `ascii` database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. However the db you are connecting to is "ascii)". I assume you mean to use "ascii". So the reason you aren't seeing any results is that the "ascii)" db is empty.